# OpenCV/C++ for loop does not break

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, for-loop

I'm currently using C++ and writing a program that depends on OpenCV. I'm having trouble with two nested for-loops.

```
float invalue = 0;
float columnvalue = 0;
CvScalar rscal;


printf("%i\n", height);
printf("%i\n", width);

for(int i=0; i < height; i++)
{
 columnvalue = 0;
 printf("%i\n", i);

 for(int j=0; j < width; j++)
  {
    rscal = cvGet2D(matrix,i,j);            
    columnvalue += rscal.val[0];        
   }

 printf("%f\n", columnvalue);
 holder[i] = columnvalue;       
 }
```

The problem I'm having is that i does not seem to increment past 2. The output of this code is:

```
480
640
0
100
1
113
2
200
```

And then the code stops running. Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How is `holder` defined and allocated?

Comment: holder was defined a little before this. float holder[] = width;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what did you intended, so i may be wrong, but i think it should be `float holder[] = new float[width];`. I think that currently you are trying to access the element of array that simply doesn't exist and you are changing value of `height` or `i`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the program terminates trying to access unallocated memory locations holder[i]. You can verify this by commenting out the line

```
holder[i] = columnvalue;
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not declare the array correctly! I fixed this by declaring it as float holder[width]; and not float holder[] = width, which I had before.